# Issue in Google In App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

InAppBilling module does not call onActivityResult of activity object passed in 'launchPurchaseFlow()' method. It happens only when user leave the application on 'Accept & Buy' Screen after Inapp billing purchase flow has been started and comes back and completes the purchase flow.

Rather then calling onActivityResult of same activity object, the InAppBilling module creates the a new object of same Activity class.

Comment: can you post some code here and make sure you are doind proper formatting of code.

Comment: Finally I found the answer every time I upload a apk the base 64 key is changed that should be used for next time in code when you upload next version of apk